# Archived Tasks in jBPM 6.4

Tags: redhat, jbpm, business-process-management, redhat-bpm

I would like to know if there is a REST API call to list an archived set of Tasks in jBPM 6.x

As far as I know, there are just two query calls available:

```
[GET] /query/runtime/task
[GET] /query/task
```

Neither of those can retrieve all archived tasks. I saw in the BPM Suite dashboard that all tasks can be listed somehow. I'm wondering if there is an API available for that operation.

Answer (score -1):

To list completed tasks try with below REST API:

[GET] /query/runtime/task?taskstatus=Completed

Comment: It will only list the completed tasks for the uncompleted processes. I need to list all tasks, including the fail and exited processes.